# NO XML Spring-data-jpa datasources and Junit tests (ManagedType fail)

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4, spring-data-jpa

I have the following classes working as intended if the project is run under "spring-boot:run" maven directive.

But now I'm trying to create a few test-cases just as good practice and I'm struggling to make JUnit understand my XML-less configuration... Here's the relevant code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "emfIntranet", transactionManagerRef = "tmIntranet", basePackages = {"com.vnt.intranet.repositories"})
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "databases.sistemas")
public class IntranetPersistence {

    private String address;
    private String schema;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String eclipselinklog;
    private Boolean sqllog;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dsIntranet")
    DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://" + address + "/" + schema);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setInitialSize(3);
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(3);
        dataSource.setMaxTotal(10);
        return dataSource;
    }

    private EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter getEclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter() {
        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.PostgreSQLPlatform");
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(sqllog);
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "emfIntranet")
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(getEclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.vnt.intranet.entities");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.weaving", "false");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.logging.level", eclipselinklog); 

        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "tmIntranet")
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getSchema() {
        return schema;
    }

    public void setSchema(String schema) {
        this.schema = schema;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEclipselinklog() {
        return eclipselinklog;
    }

    public void setEclipselinklog(String eclipselinklog) {
        this.eclipselinklog = eclipselinklog;
    }

    public Boolean getSqllog() {
        return sqllog;
    }

    public void setSqllog(Boolean sqllog) {
        this.sqllog = sqllog;
    }
}
```

Testcase:

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = {Application.class}, initializers =     ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ServiceOrderRepositoryTest {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceOrderRepositoryTest.class);

    @Autowired
    ServiceOrderRepository serviceOrderRepository;

    @Test
    public void serviceOrderTest() {
        ServiceOrder serviceOrderList = serviceOrderRepository.findOne(51152L);
        logger.debug("{}", serviceOrderList);
        assertThat(serviceOrderList, is(not(nullValue())));
    }
}
```

The error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No [ManagedType] was found for the key class [com.vnt.mkdata.entities.ServiceOrder] in the Metamodel - please verify that the [Managed] class was referenced in persistence.xml using a specific <class>com.vnt.mkdata.entities.ServiceOrder</class> property or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element.
```

This test-case will work, of course, if I create a persistence.xml file but that's exactly the point, I don't want one...

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out one needs to provide an unique PersistenceUnitName for the datasource... Apparently something is more automated when running from "spring-boot:run" and it's created auto-magically.

So, I just added "factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("some-unique-name");" to each DataSource

```
factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.vnt.intranet.entities");
factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("intranet");
```